# error while importing .wpress format into wordpress localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

While importing my backup (`.wpress`) format through [All-in-One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) plugin I am getting this following error:

> Your php is 32-bit. In order to import your file, please change your
>   PHP version to 64-bit and try again. Technical
>   details(https://help.servmask.com/knowledgebase/php-32bit/).

I am using 7.1.13 version of xampp. Still its showing me same. Kindly help me out.

Comment: you need to instal xampp 64 bit setup

Comment: I did not find 64 bit xampp for windows if you have the link please provide me.

Comment: check this http://download.cnet.com/XAMPP/3000-10248_4-10703782.html